# Getting crash while start the activity

Tags: switchcompat

java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.text.StaticLayout.(StaticLayout.java:59)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.makeLayout(SwitchCompat.java:602)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.onMeasure(SwitchCompat.java:522)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16845)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1199)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:609)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16845)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:824)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:500)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16845)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16845)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16845)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2368)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16845)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2296)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1362)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1559)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1239)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6278)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:654)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SwitchCompat then use android:textOn="On" and android:textOff="Off" in xml. Because the textOn and textOff labels are null as a default value.

Comment: This will hide the switch compat icon selection from the layout